# Does HttpHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation validate or not?

Tags: c#, .net, http, dotnet-httpclient

I'm a bit confused by the name of this function.
Why isn't it just `TryAdd`? What is it that it doesn't validate? If I use this function, can it still throw in some cases? Can I somehow "try to add" without getting any exceptions and only false returned if it fails?

EDIT:
I think the 2 questions are opposing each other. If I call with `TryAddWithoutValidation` does it actually add the invalid headers or it just returns false if they are invalid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [HttpHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpHeaders.cs#L108) returns false if the key is null/empty OR it's in the list of [invalid headers](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpHeaders.cs#L379).

The [Add](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpHeaders.cs#L52) method, besides throwing exceptions instead of returning false, calls the method [ParseAndAddValue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpHeaders.cs#L1047). Internally it gets a parser for each key you try to add and only accepts the value if the parse is successfull (checking if the key you're trying to add is valid for that kind of request, for example).

Comment: But why is it named "WithoutValidation" if it checks whether the key is in the list of invalid headers? What is the validation which it isn't doing?

Comment: @ditoslav It calls [`ParseAndAddValue`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpHeaders.cs#L1047). It checks if the key you provided is valid in your context, if it supports multiple values or not etc. This is basically the validation that the `TryAddWithouValidation` refers in its name. The list of invalid headers is checked either way.

Comment: But why is it called "WithoutValidation" if it does validation?

Comment: @ditoslav probably because the validation that the author of the method was thinking about was `ParseAndAddValue`, ignoring the fact that the `TryCheckHeaderName` does some validations too. Yeah, you can say it's a misleading name :)

Answer (score 0):

`HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage` do not accept `Content` related headers, by convention, you are supposed to add `Content` related headers into `HttpContent`.

So if you call

```
 response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", ...);
 response.Headers.Add("Content-Length",...);
```

you will get an exception.

But you still don't want to follow `HttpClient`'s convention and you may need this while you are proxying some requests. Then you can call.

```
 response.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", ...);
 response.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Length",...);
```

This will add headers and it will send/receive headers without validating.

Comment: So it will add them and return false because they aren't actually valid?